# Capturing only pixels from Google Glass camera

Tags: colors, camera, rgb, google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to capture only a few pixels from the Google Glass camera at regular intervals, to obtain color data over time. Is there a way, to save battery life, to only capture a few pixels rather than take a full image every time and have to post-render it (which is much more intensive and battery-consuming)? Perhaps this is configured on the hardware level, and thus I cannot do such a thing.

As an alternative, I was hoping the light sensor would give RGB data, but it appears to be a monochromatic light level that is provided in units of lux.